# Determining a $2\times 2$ matrix via its characteristic equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

If I know the following:

- $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix.
- $A$ has characteristic equation $(\lambda - 2)^2=0$

We can determine that we are dealing with a matrix of the form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}2&a\\b&2\end{bmatrix}$$
Is there any one piece of additional information, other than simply knowing the value, that can be used to identify either $a$ or $b$ above? We know that either $a$ or $b$ is zero already.

---

For example:

- Knowing if it is diagonalisable, should mean $a=b=0$ - I imagine.
- Knowing the trace(we can already see) yields no information.

---

**Let's not consider the case where it is diagonalisable, since that is unintersting**

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$, this matrix isn't in the form you have but it has the same characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @MathNewbie Indeed, I made a mistake when thinking in terms of Jordan form

Comment: The characteristic polynomial tells you only the (algebraic) eigenvalues of a matrix, including multiplicity---no more, no less.

Comment: (One *can* with only a little effort parameterize all of the nondiagonalizable matrices with the given characteristic polynomial, though.)

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic equation will yield equivalent forms. One of those forms is the diagonal matrix you write, with $a=b=0$

Comment: Indeed. I mean what can we determine about the $2\times 2$ matrix in general based on the characteristic equation and one addition piece of information.

In the case you have given, being diagonalisable yields that case, but I am interested in general(also this is in the question body)

Comment: Actually it is diagonalisable since it yields two non zero eigen values. Therefore the matrix is not singular. So saying it is diagonalisable, is superfluous information, already discernible from the characteristic equation itself

Comment: That is false. Consider the Jordan form: $$\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: My mistake, i admit. Still i wouldn't find diagonalisable condition, good enough to determine the matrix.

Comment: It would be sufficient by Jordan normal form to determine its' conjugacy class, I.e. $\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$. In fact all matrices with the given characteristic equation are similar to one of these two forms

Answer (score 0):

Jordan form may be
$$J = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$
or
$$J = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}.$$
Hence your matrix is
$$A = T^{-1}JT=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$
or
$$A = T^{-1}JT=T^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}T,$$
where $T$ is invertible matrix.